# Cassandra eating hard drive space

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra, nodes, opscenter

I'm using Cassandra with OpsCenter (3 servers = 2 nodes, 1 server for OpsCenter) and for some reason every day going my hard drive space is taken more 1G and nothing change on the DB (no inserts / updates) only reading few rows.

Is it make sense? Do I need to delete something every few days? cache?

I'm using AWS EC2 for all the servers.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this space is used by OpsCenter metrics?

Comment: It's make sense that OpsCenter store all the metrics on the Cassandra database and therefor the space taken. I want to confirm that and maybe there is a way to delete old metrics.

Comment: Does `nodetool cleanup` recover much space? If it does, consider periodically running it.

Comment: @MartinGallagher No, It's taken 1G every day and I'm not adding new data.

Comment: One thing to try would be from the OS look at the data dir and see what subdirectories are taking the most space up.  You can drill down till you know the exact tables that are causing the issue.  Once we know that the proper changes can be made to control the situation.